# Solve for unknown variable with other dependent variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am stuck with the following problem:

Let's assume a car seller has three models with the following sales:

Model A: 300cars //
Model B: 250cars //
Model C: 400 cars

But also the following caveats: i) price for model A should be 10% lower than model B and the price for model C should be 10% higher than model B ii) the average price of all cars sold should be 50,000.

=> now I am looking for how to set the price of model B to meet all requirements. When using the goal seek from excel I know that model B should be priced at 49,479 USD but I was wondering how to solve this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sympy package to do what you want. Basically, you tell it to resolve your equation. Here's how your problem would look like

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq

price = symbols('price')

eq = Eq((300 * 0.9 * price + 250 * price + 1.1 * 400 * price) / (300 + 250 + 400), 50000)

sol = solve(eq)

print(sol)

>>> [49479.1666666667]
```